# If $f_n \to f $ in measure can we say that $\ |f_n| \to |f|$ in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f_n \to f $ in measure can we say that $\ |f_n| \to |f|$ in measure ( asumme we are in finite measure spaces ).

I think it can not be true because $||f_n|-|f||\le |f_n-f|$

Comment: The inequality you've given is exactly why it **is** true.

Comment: How about not finite measure spaces?

Comment: This holds even in non-finite measure spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's true. For if $f_n \to f$ in measure on a space $(X,\mu)$, then for every $\varepsilon > 0$,

$$\mu\{x\in X : ||f_n(x)| - |f(x)|| > \varepsilon\} \le \mu\{x \in X : |f_n(x) - f(x)| > \varepsilon\} \to 0,$$

and hence $|f_n| \to |f|$ in measure.